# How to send a push notification from Node.js using REST API in MobileFirst Foundation 8?

Tags: node.js, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Who knows what did I wrong in implementing this on a Node.js server?

The parameter were valid and it worked with the Poster on my local Mac.
Node.js and MFP 8 Beta are running locally on the Mac.

[image]

Here is the code for the server.js file and the steps are:

1. prepare the header
2. MFP Settings
3. create post options
4. create the JSON object for MFP Push
5. Do the POST call using http
6. write the json Push Data

   ```
   app.post('/award', function(req, res){
   var notificationMessage = req.body.message;
       // prepare the header
       // MFP Settings
       var theAuthorization = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp…….Wg";
       var appname = 'com.ionicframework.checkapp';
       var http = require('http');
       var theHost = 'localhost'; // here only the domain name
       var thePort = 9080;
       var thePath = 'imfpush/v1/apps/' + appname + '/messages';
       var theMethode = 'POST';
       var postheaders = {
       'Authorization' : theAuthorization ,
       'Content-Type'  : 'application/json'
       };
       // the post options
       var optionspost = {
       host : theHost,
       port : thePort,
       path : thePath,
       method : theMethode,
       headers : postheaders
       };
       // create the JSON object for MFP Push
       var jsonObject = JSON.stringify({"message":{"alert" :notificationMessage}});
       console.info('---> Options prepared:');
       console.info(optionspost);
       console.info('---> Do the POST call');
       // do the POST call using http
       var reqPost = http.request(optionspost, function(res) {
       console.log("---> statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
       console.log("---> headers: ", res.headers);
       res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.info('---> POST result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(d);
        console.info('\n\n---> POST completed');
       });
       });
       // write the json Push Data
       reqPost.write(jsonObject);
       reqPost.end();
       reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
       console.error(e);
       });
       res.end("OK");
     });
   ```

I get the statusCode:400 and this is console output:

Options prepared:

```
{ host: 'localhost',
  port: 9080,
  path: 'imfpush/v1/apps/com.ionicframework.checkapp/messages',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: 
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp3ayI6......DjbgjqVz5JFVcT8i5k_JWg' } }
---> Do the POST call
---> statusCode:  400
---> headers:  { 'content-length': '0',
  connection: 'Close',
  date: 'Wed, 22 Jun 2016 12:02:50 GMT' }
```

These were my information sources: 
https://isolasoftware.it/2012/05/28/call-rest-api-with-node-js/ and 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-push-notifications/

Comment: A few notes: Can you use Wireshark to inspect what happens on the network? See the details of the response? - The Bearer token is only valid for a certain time, can you check it is still valid in Postman? - I notice that your json body has no "target" recipient - who should receive this notification?

Comment: Also I think the `path` needs to start with a `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Idan for the text validation and @Nathan for the comment.

I found the problem and now it works.
I changed the order of the request preparation and some changes in the code.

1. prepare the header
2. MFP Settings
3. create the JSON object for MFP Push -> **Moved UP**
4. create post options                 -> **Moved Down**
5. Do the POST call using http
6. write the json Push Data

Code changes:

1. Insert **'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject)** inside the header.
2. Adding a slash to the path **var thePath = '/imfpush/v1/apps/' + appname + '/messages';**

Comment: I created a Node.JS module you can Reuse on your own risk.
Take a look here in the blog: 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/10/18/using-mff-8-push-service-rest-api-in-a-nodejs-based-server/

Comment: It's "Content-Length", not "Centent-Length"