# Mobile first 8.0 (Push Notification and Adaptor)

Tags: cordova, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am working on push notification on device from server using mobile first platform 8.0. For that I need JAVA API of mobile first to send notification but didnot found. in document also mention only 2 ways to send notification first using console and other using rest client.

Share mobile first API(if exsist) or i used normal gcm and apns dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Java API. There are REST endpoints that you call to in order to send the notification. You can call these REST endpoints from any language you'd like... be it JavaScript, Java, Swift or anything else.

The documentation mentions that in order to send a notification **not from** the MobileFirst Operations Console, you need to first create a confidential client with the appropriate access token to the MobileFirst Server, and then use this in order to call the REST endpoints to send a notification.

See here:

- Confidential Clients: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/confidential-clients/
- Sending notifications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#rest-apis

Call REST endpoints in Java: https://www.google.co.il/search?q=java+call+rest+endpoint&oq=java+call+rest+endpoint&aqs=chrome..69i57.3272j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Node.js example with MobileFirst Foundation 8: [How to send a push notification from Node.js using REST API in MobileFirst Foundation 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969389/how-to-send-a-push-notification-from-node-js-using-rest-api-in-mobilefirst-found)

Comment: So In order to send push i need a make 2rest call 1. authorize my server 2. for push. According to me which make unnecessary

Comment: @rahul, without step 1 ( authorize) any one would be able to access your server and send notifications. That is not an ideal scenario